# Using Dictionary<TKey,TValue>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>) Constructor in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, constructor

I am confused as to how to use

```
Dictionary<TKey,TValue>(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>)
```

constructor of Dictionary Class in C#. A working example will be very helpful.

Thanks

Satish Chandra

Comment: What's your use case? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

With the constructor you mentioned you can pass an already existing Dictionary as parameter.
e.g.:

```
Dictionary<int,string> firstDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 0, "0" }, { 1, "hallo" } };
Dictionary<int,string> secondDictionary;

void InitSecondDict()
{
    secondDictionary = new Dictionary<int,string>(firstDictionary);
}
```

What this constructor does is copying the elements from "firstDictionary" into the new Dictionary<int,string>-object "secondDictionary"

Comment: Thank you so much for a very quick and effective response.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dictionary<string, string> openWith = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

More info and examples on [Micrsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick and effective response.